# Is there a way to detect whether something is immutable?

Tags: raku

In Raku a scalar might be immutable or it might be an actual variable:

```
 my $a := 6;  # constant
 my $b  = 6;  # variable
```

Is there a programmatic way to check whether a scalar is immutable without just trying to change it and seeing if it works?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, a slight terminological correction (not to be nitpicky, but just because this area is a bit tricky and being precise with our terms can help).

It's not really right to say that `my $a := 6` is a *constant*; that expression *binds* `$a` to the value `6`, which prevents you from *assigning* a different value to $a (with the `=` operator).  However, you can still rebind a new value to `$a` (with the `:=` operator).  This means that `$a` can still, in a sense, be mutated – or, at least, can be made to point to something new.  For a truly constant `$a`, you should use either `constant $a` or change `$a` to a sigil-less variable (`my \a = 6`).

Now to the actual answer to your question: To determine whether `$a` is bound or assigned to a value, you can use `$a.VAR.WHAT`.  If `$a` is assigned a value, this will return the type of container, `(Scalar)`; if it is bound, then it will return the type of the bound value.

As far as I know, there isn't a way to tell the difference between an `$a` bound to a value and one that's a constant, though I would love to be wrong about that.

The code below illustrates what I just said:

```
my $a = 1;
say $a.VAR.WHAT; # OUTPUT: «(Scalar)»
$a = 2;
say $a;          # OUTPUT: «2»

my $b := 1;
say $b.VAR.WHAT;# OUTPUT: «(Int)»
$b := 2;
say $b;          # OUTPUT: «2»

constant $c = 1;
say $c.VAR.WHAT; # OUTPUT: «(Int)»
# $c := 2; ILLEGAL 
say $c;          # OUTPUT: «1»
```

Comment: In this space, correct terminology is a requirement, not a nit-pick.

Comment: "However, you can still rebind a new value to $a (with the := operator)"  Yes, very good point.

Comment: Indeed, there's no runtime difference between a `constant $a = 42` and `my $a := 42`.  The impossibility of rebinding to it, is determined at compile time when the compiler "sees" that the left hand side was defined as a `constant` and decides to throw a "Cannot use bind operator with this left-hand side" error.

Comment: "For a truly constant `$a`, you should use either `constant $a` or change `$a` to a sigil-less variable (`my \a = 6`)." Methinks a footnote is in order. (Or perhaps a site that's a sight of a slight terminological sleight.) The constantness you speak of is only in relation to the *reference* to the value bound to the variable, not the value itself. Consider `constant foo = 42; foo does role { method Str { '99' } }; say foo; # 99`. While you might (quite rightly) say all I've done is altered a method of that particular `42`, the point is Raku doesn't yet support true absolute immutability.

Answer (score 8):

Another way, using [multiple dispatch](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Multi-dispatch):

```
my $a := 6;  # constant
my $b  = 6;  # variable

multi sub mutable($ is rw) { True }
multi sub mutable($) { False }

say mutable($a); # False
say mutable($b); # True
say mutable(42); # False
```